# Data manipulation on java side or on db side using virtual tables or views?

Tags: android, view, android-sqlite

Im developing an android application which uses sqlite db(very similar to a quiz program).

- There will be 6-7 tables and totally 2000+ rows.
- Each table consists at least 200+ rows. In my program , I will get only 25 rows at one time(one test/quiz). I have already divided into groups  my tables for easy handling
- Group members (rows)  are constant.
- Each rows contains 4-5 columns and 2 columns consist 1 sentence(Text).
- Also I want to show only one row on the screen but in a randomized way. Randomizing will be in the group only.
- Data will be read-only( except that user's profile , highscore , points etc)

What I want to learn is :

1) Should I do the getting and manipulating data stuff at the db side or in a java class i.e. a-) java class gets data directly from db and randomizes it and shows it or b-) using some views or virtual tables ? What are the differences in terms of :

- Easy management/handling of code
- Source usage
- Program Speed

2) Also I want to learn the differences of using a virtual table or  a view in sqlite for my application. Which is better in terms of above criteria?